# Unbold function for contenteditable

Tags: javascript, contenteditable, dom-selection

I am working on a contenteditable editor (in a div element).

In that, I am making a function for making the selected element **bold**. Till now this is my approach:

```
 sselection= window.getSelection();

console.log(sselection.getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer.tagName);
    if ((sselection!=="" || sselection.isCollapsed!==undefined || sselection.isCollapsed=="false") && sselection.getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer.tagName!="B" && WhereNodeBelongs()==true && window.getComputedStyle(sselection.anchorNode.parentNode)["font-weight"]!="700") {
        if (sselection.rangeCount) {
            range = sselection.getRangeAt(0);
            toReplace = range.commonAncestorContainer;
            var newNode = document.createElement("b");
            newNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode(sselection.toString()));
            range.deleteContents();
            range.insertNode(newNode);
            saveState();
        }
    } else if (window.getComputedStyle(window.getSelection().anchorNode.parentNode)["font-weight"]=="700") {
        window.getSelection().anchorNode.parentNode.style.fontWeight= "400";
    }

}
```

The code which makes the text bold is working alright. However the code that makes a **bold** element unbold seems to have a problem. After I unbold the selection, the innerHTML is like this:

`<b style="font-weight: 400;"><b>element called nothing</b></b>`

How can I make it so that it becomes like this:

`element called nothing`

Also the bold elements can have other styles like italic, underline, etc. How can I make it such that the unbold function *only removes the bold in a clean format, and nothing else*?

Comment: P.S. Before anyone recommends document.execCommand and queryCommand, I must add that I have already seen it but it is getting depreciated in most browsers.

Comment: Using CSS classes would most likely do what you need.

Comment: I didn't get you exactly. Could you elaborate a bit more on your comment?

Comment: Instead of inline styles, style the element with a CSS class, that way you can find the element easily when unbolding. Notice also, that the semantic meaning of [b tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/b) has changed in HTML5.

Comment: Oh I think I got your idea now. Will certainly try implementing it.